# Getting headers data from JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question on obtaining data using JQuery.  I have this HTML code -

```
              Sat 08 Jan</th><td  headers="tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2">&#160;7&deg;C   &#47; 2&deg;C</td><td  

              Sun 09 Jan</th><td  headers="tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2">&#160;5&deg;C   &#47; 2&deg;C</td>

              Mon 10 Jan</th><td  headers="tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2">&#160;4&deg;C   &#47; 1&deg;C</td>
```

I cannot change the HTML.

I have to get the degrees data for each header.  I have tried

```
              var testData = $(data).find("[headers='tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2']");
        console.log(testData.html());
```

but it looks like it is only storing one temperature.  I have tried for each loops with no success.

I need to store it as an array so I can pull the line out separately. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) here

```
var testData = $(data).find("[headers='tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2']").map(function(){
    return $(this).html()
}).get();// now testData is an array with the html contents of the targeted elements
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LvZEb/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I still cant seem to get this to work, can you show an example of each line separately in console.log.

Comment: @user2721700 see the attached fiddle

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/EBZ8j/)

An other solution is to get value of each td that has `headers=tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2` and  add it to an array of values:

```
  var values=Array();
 //Loop that iterate over t
 $('td[headers="tbl241id1_0 tbl241id0_2"]').each(function(index,value){
   values.push($(this).text());

  });
```

Comment: another great solution to retrieve the value. The first answer by Arun worked for me as well, but thanks again for the quick response and the jfiddle example.